# principal component analysis, label of component?

Tags: r, pca

I have a dataframe with 17 columns (each column for one gene) and 34 rows (each row for one patient)

```
Patient EXO1 MLH1 MSH2 MSH3 MSH6 PCNA PMS1 PMS2 POLE POLE2 POLE3 POLH RFC2 
1651109    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     0     1    0    0      
1651648    0    1    1    1    1    0    1    0    1     0     0    1    1  
........
```

The name of the dataframe is, say, `testdb`.
Then I run

```
res=princomp(testdb);  
summary(res);
```

and that shows

```
Importance of components:  
                          Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3     Comp.4     Comp.5  
Standard deviation     0.6577676 0.4757815 0.4138278 0.39002636 0.37679135  
Proportion of Variance 0.2822533 0.1476757 0.1117206 0.09923892 0.09261812  
Cumulative Proportion  0.2822533 0.4299290 0.5416497 0.64088859 0.73350672  
....
```

It is stupid that the names are `comp.1` `comp.2` `comp.3`....
How can I map the name back to gene name?
I know `biplot(res)` will print some of the genes on the output graph, but that obviously is not the correct way to get gene name.

Comment: The principal components are combinations of all your variables, it doesn't make sense to map them back onto your original variables. What were you expecting to get out of the PCA analysis?

Comment: No. PCA should let me know what variables are the primary contributor.  If not, I dont know why PCA was invented. Backward/forward variable selection is good enough to tell the primary contributor, but is affected by the order of variable enter the model. PCA is not sensitive to order.

Comment: @user1143669 PCA let you know which variables are primary contributors to the largest variances within your data. The orthogonal vectors along these variances are your principle components. The contributions of the variables to each PC is represented by the loading matrix (`? loadings`). @Marius is absolutely right: Unless your loading matrix is not an identity matrix, it doesn't make sense at all to map specific variables back to certain PCs.

Comment: BTW: It looks as if your variables are not normally distributed but of binary nature instead. You should reconsider if PCA is the right tool for your data. (Binary) Discriminant Analysis might be more appropriate. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16331/how-to-perform-principal-components-analysis-on-binary-yes-no-data-using-spss/16335#16335 is a good primer for further reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Although most of this has already been stated in comments, I'm turning this into an answer.*

The components of a primary component analysis are linear combinations of your original variables. So there is no one-to-one mapping between components and genes. Excepting special cases, every component describes multiple genes. Some of them with a positive and some with a negative contribution. Some with large and some with small absolute values. You can see these contributions from the loading matrix: enter `loadings(res)` and you will see the composition of each component.

You can find the gene with maximum absolute value in the column for a specific component in the loadings matrix. That way you could identify something like a “primary contributor” to each component. But unless that contribution was *very* close to one, treating the component as a synonym for the gene would be misleading at best. If you want your analysis in terms of individual genes, PCA is not the right tool.

If you are sure you want the “main contributor” despite the above warnings, the following code does that:

```
l <- loadings(res)
rownames(l)[apply(l, 2, function(x) which.max(abs(x)))]
```

Comment: if this is the case, what does R's `biplot` do to produce labels for the loading vectors? Does it do the above? E.g., here, where do the following labels come from? http://www.datavis.ca/papers/viscollin/figs/cars-biplot32.jpg

Comment: @Tommy: afaics `biplot` will simply project the vectors down. I.e. take the first two columns in the loadings matrix, and use the corresponding two-element row vectors as vectors to associate with the row label.

Comment: @MvG  sorry, can you clarify? where does the label come from?